# Global Gemfile in the user's home directory using rbenv: good idea?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I am using rbenv to manage my gems, locally in my projects but also globally, on a Linux box.

When I bump my global ruby version (set in `~/.rbenv/version`), I always forget to install some of my utility gems, that I need for development mainly.
Examples are rubocop for linting, minitest for some scripts I have scattered in my files, etc.
Using my package manager is not a really flexible solution (not so up-to-date, many gems are not packaged etc).

How should I proceed to keep a list of these gems I want to always have globally accessible, whatever the project I am currently working on?
Should I have a Gemfile and a Gemfile.lock in my home directory? How could I hide them then (.Gemfile/.Gemfile.lock)?

So that once I change the global ruby version, then a

```
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle
```

and I have everything up and running?
In this case would I have to prepend every command with `bundle exec`?

Is there a better way to manage this problem that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [`rbenv-default-gems`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-default-gems).

Just install it into rbenv's plugins folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-default-gems.git $(rbenv root)/plugins/rbenv-default-gems
```

Place a file named `default-gems` into your rbenv's root folder:

```
touch $(rbenv root)/default-gems
```

Add gems in `$(rbenv root)/default-gems` by name, one per line. You may need to optionally specify a version string after the name, or `--pre` to install a pre-release version. For example:

```
bundler
bcat ~>0.6
rails --pre
```

Comment: Really nice indeed. I had not thought of looking inside the rbenv plugins. Out of curiosity do you think a global Gemfile would have been possible?

Comment: I have never thought about a global Gemfile. I wonder how that works if there a multiple nested Gemfiles with various versions of the same gems. To me `default-gems` seems much clearer.